# Echo selected in drop down menu

Tags: php, html

I am getting confused now.
Why am I not able to echo an selected item?

```
                  echo'
                  <form class="form-horizontal form-calculator" id="interval" action="includes/toolbox_interval.php" method="post">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="interval">Kies interval</label>
                          <select class="form-control" name="interval" id="interval">
                            <option></option>
                            <option'; if($row['days'] == 7){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } echo 'value="7">Wekelijks</option>
                            <option value="14">2 wekelijks</option>
                            <option value="30">Maandelijks</option>
                            <option value="91">Elk kwartaal</option>
                            <option value="365">Jaarlijks</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  </form>';
```

[image]

Comment: Try this code `<option'. if($row['days'] == 7){ . 'selected="selected"' .} . 'value="7">Wekelijks</option>`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Comment: No Nawin; you need to have the semi-colon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muiter,

For one, you need spaces, try the following--

```
<option '; if($row['days'] == 7){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } echo ' value="7">Wekelijks</option>
```

**Notice the space after *option* tag and before the *value* attribute**

If you do not have the spaces, here are the scenarios you are facing...

1. The *if* condition has met. As a result, your resulting *option* tag will be:

   ```
   <optionselected="selected"value="7">Wekelijks</option>
   ```
2. The *if* condition has not met. In which case, your resulting *option* tag will be:

   ```
   <optionvalue="7">Wekelijks</option>
   ```

Hope this helps!

-Rush

Comment: It helps!. Can you explain what the difference the spaces make?

Comment: Yes if without space the code is `<optionseleceted` Nice @rushilkumar

Comment: @Muiter, i will edit my post to provide the explanation... but in short Nawin is right. Thank you Nawin

Comment: Thank you for your efforts Rush.

Comment: You got it Muiter! Glad I could help.